# Steps to perform after power cut to mac

Tags: catalina, disk-utility

If the power is interrupted to mac, what steps, if any, should be performed, even if startup appears fine.

Such as entering recovery mode, running First Aid Disk Utility?

Comment: Anecdotally - I've never done any steps at all; even on machines  [with no UPS] with otherwise 24/7 uptime, constantly for 10 years or more; simply set to boot after a power-cut. I'm sure you'd notice if anything had gone 'boo-boo'. I've had machines go "Bang! Ouch!" after bad episodes, but they required new drives & recovery from backup. Up within an hour.

Comment: RE: "If the power is interrupted to mac" --  That's what a UPS is for, as well as for surge protection.

Comment: Have one that just sits cycling through my photos folder 10 seconds each photo at random. Any loss of power and it restarts and continues. Over 6000 photos and it is a white plastic shell mac. Not died yet but all photos backed up so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know nothing.

Journaled file systems do not usually lose data when they are shut down unexpectedly, the journal maintains the consistency of the filesystem.  Data that was being written right at the power loss may be gone. The actual file data does also depend on how the app writes data back, if it updates a file in place then the update might not be complete and so you have an incorrect file which you will have to check manually, if the app uses a safe save mechanism ie write to a temporary file and then move that to your file then that should be consistent but might be an older version. So you will need to check at the app level. Some apps will be able to recover better than others. For others you will have to look at backups.

I think disks are the only part of the system that have different behaviour between and expected shutdown e.g. by /sbin/shutdown or one by power loss,

Unjournaled file systems can lose data much more easily and that is why you should check the filesystem, the main example of this is filesystems using a form of MSDOS FAT or old Unix filesystems. Nowadays you should onlyu see these on Flash drives or other drives used for moving data between systems and devices.

Comment: The idea of a journaled file system is not that it never loses data, but that the filesystem is always in a consistent state.  It's *harder* to lose data, but it is not impossible.

Comment: Journaling protects the integrity of the filesystem, but not the *contents* of files. Any file that was being written to or modified when the power cut might be left in an inconsistent state, so it's best to check any files you had open when it cut. Since the contents of the files are managed by whatever program uses the files, there's no standard way to do this; you have to check them in whatever program you use to interact with that particular type of file. Also, consider this a good time to think about/verify your backup(s)... because bad things *do* happen sometimes.